# using css3 gradient feature with xhtml - is it possible?

Tags: xhtml, css

I can't use html5. I need to use only xhtml. Will css3 gradient and border-radius work with xhtml??

Comment: Sigh... what have those crazy Web people ingrained into innocent minds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works perfectly. Not in IE though. For IE, you have to use filter like this:

```
IE 5.5-7:
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#FF0000FF, endColorStr=#FFFFFFFF, GradientType=1);


IE 8:
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FF0000FF, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF, GradientType=1)";
```

For rounded div corners in IE I recommend the Curvy Corners javascript. Here's a [Link](http://www.curvycorners.net/).

Comment: IE9 supports some of the CSS3 functionality. It does not support gradients though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is no direct relation between HTML versions and CSS versions.

If the browser supports the CSS style, it will work regardless of the HTML version you use.

(The exception is that some features may be disabled if you don't have a valid doctype so that the page renders in Quirks Mode.)